# How to make adjacency list with vector

Tags: c++, vector

How can I make adjacency lists with vector with class in C++?

**I have only:**

```
class Graph{
     private:
     int nodeid;
     vector<int>Neighbours;
}
```

Comment: You could make your nodeid's powers of 2 only, and then store a bitmask of all the nodes your node is adjacent to at that position in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
class Node
{
  int data;
  std:vector<std::weak_ptr<Node>> Neighbours;
};

std::shared_ptr<Node> graph;
```

In addition you need a container managing the lifetime of a node (Graph might be a special node maintaining it).